# Deploy .net core app to linux in visual studio?

Tags: c#, linux, visual-studio, publish

I am building a .net core app in Visual Studio 2017. I would like to automate my the publishing process to a linux machine.

This is my current process:

1. In Visual Studio, click Publish tab, select Publish
2. Open `WinSCP`, login to target linux machine
3. Open the folder `solution\myapp\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.2\publish\`
4. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> select all in publish folder, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> copy all the files, then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> paste in `WinSCP` target directory
5. Open `PuTTY`, login to target linux machine, restart the app using `dotnet myapp.dll`

Could I automate these steps when publishing from Visual Studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [dotnet-publish-ssh](https://github.com/albekov/dotnet-publish-ssh).

It works like `dotnet publish`, but allows you to copy your app over SSH to your target Linux machine.

Here is my config:

```
dotnet publish-ssh --ssh-host <host> --ssh-user <user> --ssh-password <pass> --ssh-path /var/<myapp> --configuration Release --framework netcoreapp3.1 --runtime linux-x64 --self-contained false /p:PublishSingleFile=true
```

To restart the app you may try PowerShell with Posh-SSH module:

```
Import-Module Posh-SSH
$serverAddress = "host addr"
$user = "user"
$pass = ConvertTo-SecureString "pass" -AsPlainText -Force
$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($user, $pass)
$launchFolder = "/var/<myapp>"
$sshSession = New-SSHSession -ComputerName $serverAddress -Credential $creds -ErrorAction Stop
Invoke-SSHCommand -SSHSession $sshSession -Command "<your restart command>"
Remove-SSHSession -SSHSession $sshSession
```

Comment: I'm not even sure how to install, use this add on in VS 2019.  I couldn't find any documentation